# org.hibernate.type.TextType and Oracle

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jpa, oracle11g

We use Hibernate as a JPA provider and we have a class with a large object field marked with

```
@Lob
@Type( type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType" )
private String someString;
```

The column is created as

```
SOMESTRING            LONG()
```

This works flawlessly with PostgreSQL and MySQL. With Oracle when persisting the object

```
entityManager.persist( object );
```

we get an `org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update` exception.

Removing the `@Type( type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType" )` annotation will solve the problem with Oracle but introduces an encoding problem with PostgreSQL as described in [Cannot store Euro-sign into LOB String property with Hibernate/PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9993701/cannot-store-euro-sign-into-lob-string-property-with-hibernate-postgresql)

I would like to know how to define a large text field so that out program works on both PostgreSQL and Oracle. A pure JPA solution would be optimal but an Hibernate specific one will also do.

Edit:

The real exception:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-22295: cannot bind more than 4000 bytes data to LOB and LONG columns in 1 statement
```

Now, the exception I missed explains the problem and in fact the object I am persisting has more than then the large string (at least one long DBID).

Comment: Could not execute batch update only means there was any error while committing the updates. Normally there is a more concrete error message in the stack trace. please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: Just to make sure I follow the problem.. Removing `@Type` (which is the intended correct solution here btw) is problematic because of non-nationalized character support?  Aka, using Clob instead of NClob?

Comment: @SteveEbersole Yes but I notice only now that removing the `@Type` annotation has no effect on PostgreSQL (in both cases a TEXT column is created).

Comment: That should be correct.  See my answer.  But you still have problems with trying to insert characters from another character set (nationalized chars) right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719905/why-has-hibernate-switched-to-use-long-over-clob) and the only way was to extend/customize the Oracle dialect.

Comment: Extend it how, please provide a decent answer!

Comment: @AndersMetnik if you go to the linked question, you will see the code provided.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. Extended PostgreSQL81Dialect like this:

```java
public class MyPostgreSQL81Dialect extends PostgreSQL81Dialect
{

  @Override
  public SqlTypeDescriptor getSqlTypeDescriptorOverride(int sqlCode)
  {
    SqlTypeDescriptor descriptor;
    switch (sqlCode)
    {
      case Types.CLOB:
      {
        descriptor = LongVarcharTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE;
        break;
      }
      default:
      {
        descriptor = super.getSqlTypeDescriptorOverride(sqlCode);
        break;
      }
    }  
    return descriptor;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks @user1187983, It's still working like charm, I already created Dailect method for Postgre9 dialect and added your method to make it compatible with Oracle for CLOB type.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

credits should go elsewhere (to user called: @liecno), but based on one of (his) comments at the answers in the: [Postgres UTF-8 clobs with JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043992/postgres-utf-8-clobs-with-jdbc) the compatibility with Oracle as well as Postgres can be simply achieved via:

```
@Lob
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.StringClobType")
private String someString;
```

**UPDATE:**

OK, after some testing, I came to even more up to date solution, that worked for all my scenarios. As `org.hibernate.type.StringClobType` is deprecated (hibernate 4.2.x), I went to it's replacement: `org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType`.

```
@Lob
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType")
private String someString;
```

Comment: yesterday I tried the same thing `@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType")` and it did worked for both Oracle and PostgreSQL. unfortunately today this is no more working for PostgreSQL. I wonder why?

Answer (score 1):

The error means, Oracle can't handle two columns with more than 4000 bytes each in one update. In the past Oracle already had problems with this - I remember versions where only one LONG column per table was allowed. I wonder they didn't remove this issue. (I don't know if you really have a second LONG or LOB column in that table, but I guess there will be one.)

I think removing the `@Type` annotation does not generally solve the problem. In your test the effect might be then there are just less than 4000 bytes, but with other data the error also might appear.

Solution: I think you have separate the update statement into two statements, like that what I sketch here (batch update is still possible):

```
for (many rows) {
  object.setFirstLongColumn(...);
  persist(object);
  session.flush();
  object.setSecondLongColumn(...);
  persist(object);
  session.flush();
}
commit();
```

The `session.flush()` is necessary to prevent Hibernate to change the order of the database statements which could interfere with ou logic.

One more thing: [LONG is deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/server.901/a90120/ch4_dep.htm#6690) in Oracle. If you have good luck then replacing LONG with LOB in the database solves your problem.

Comment: This indeed the problem. If I remove the `@Type` annotation Hibernate maps to a LOB and the problems with Oracle are gone. But then the same code does not work with PostgreSQL (see the linked question)

Comment: If you use xml mapping files instead of annotations, then you could have different mappings for Oracle and PostgreSQL, which would solve your problem. There are still a few advantages of xml files. Would that be an alternative for you - at least for this table?

Comment: I always worked with annotations but if this could solve my problem I'll take a look ...

Comment: Probably you anyway have two different hibernate.cfg.xml, one for PostgreSQL, one for Oracle, and in one of them you enter a different path for the mapping file. You can include both mapping files for that table into your package, and only one of them is effectively used.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Lob
private String someString;
```

tells Hibernate to treat this as a "materialized CLOB".  A CLOB because of the @Lob annotation, materialized because we have to extract the String/characters from the CLOB locator.

When I say CLOB here, I mean java.sql.Types.CLOB.  So the JDBC type code.  However, Hibernate has another level of indirection here: the Dialect.  The Dialects are able to define how type codes are mapped to physical database types (used in schema export, cast calls, etc) as well as how  bind/extract operations are performed against PreparedStatement/ResultSet.  The PostgreSQL Dialects maps Types.CLOB to the physical "text" datatype; the Oracle Dialects map it to the physical CLOB datatype; the MySQL Dialects map it to the physical "longtext" datatype.

Comment: exactly. Now my problem is that with the default mapping I have no problems with Oracle but I have problems with UTF-8 characters on PostgreSQL. If I specify the type as "org.hibernate.type.TextType" the problem with UTF-8 is gone but then I cannot easily update objects on Oracle.

Comment: Well see my comment on the SO question you linked to.  Mainly, imo, this is an issue with nationalized characterset support.

Comment: The problem as far as I can tell is not with nationalized characters but as far as I remember with the dropping of bytes if character occupies more then two bytes. I will have to look back at my documentation but I remember that we had to add the mapping to avoid this particular problem with either the PostgreSQL driver or Hibernate or a combination of both.

Comment: as far as I can see, this generates blob and oid on the ddl with hibernate 5.0.12 final, so it doesn't work