# hibernate MaterializedClobType storing a long object instead of text

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity class which has a field declared as:

```
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    private String xmlString;
```

Now I have to maintain the compatibility with both **Oracle** and **PostgreSQL**. The respective column definition in DDL are `xmlString clob` and `xmlString text`. The application works well and there in only one issue with **PostgreSQL** that the value stored in column `xmlString` is of type *long object* instead of the original xml string.
As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21674143/725306) to add `@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType")` which provides compatibility with both **Oracle** and **PostgreSQL** but even after adding this annotation the value stored in **PostgreSQL** is *long object* instead of the original xml string.

The changes I made:

```
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType")
    private String xmlMessage;
```

and the value stored in `xmlString` is a number which seems to be the reference id of *long object*.

Is there any possibility to make this work on both **Oracle** and **PostgreSQL**?

---

It works well in **PostgreSQL** if I change the annotation to `@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.TextType")` but then there is schema validation failure on **Oracle**.

Comment: you hibernate version? upgrade your hibernate version to 6

Comment: the hibernate version is `5.0.12.Final` and it is not possible to immediately upgrade to hibernate 6 due to project restrictions. Can you describe what could have been the issue which is fixed in hibernate 6?

Comment: you mentioned to use hibernate 6 but that is still in alpha version http://hibernate.org/orm/releases/6.0/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to solve this problem I had created a custom dialect by extending the `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect` and overriding the `remapSqlTypeDescriptor` as follows:

```
    @Override
    public SqlTypeDescriptor remapSqlTypeDescriptor(SqlTypeDescriptor sqlTypeDescriptor)
    {
        if (sqlTypeDescriptor.getSqlType() == Types.CLOB)
        {
            log.debug("remapping CLOB to LongVarchar");
            return LongVarcharTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE;
        }
        return super.remapSqlTypeDescriptor(sqlTypeDescriptor);
    }
```

With this I do not need to annotate my entity field by

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.MaterializedClobType")
```