# Force JpaRepository to return hibernate implementation of Clob instead of oracle implementation

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have and oracle table defined this way:

```
MYCLASS_ID_PK   (NUMBER(50,0))  |MYCLASS_UUID   (VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)) |PAYLOAD    (CLOB)
```

I have a JPARepository defined this way:

```
public interface MyClassRepository extends JpaRepository<MyClass, Long> {

  Optional<MyClass> findByUuid(UUID uuid);

}
```

And I have an Entity defined this way:

```
...
import java.sql.Clob;
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "foo_myclass")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "create_myclass",
        procedureName = "CREATE_MYCLASS",
        parameters = {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "myClassUuid", type = String.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "payload", type = Clob.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "myClassId", type = Long.class)
        })
})

public class MyClass {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "myclass_id_pk")
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @Type(type = "uuid-char")
  @Column(name = "myclass_uuid")
  private UUID uuid;


  @Lob
  @Column(name = "payload")
  private Clob payload;

 }
```

I initially used String in my Entity class to link to my payload to oracle CLOB. However, my string size is a bit too big to be properly handled (confirmed with unit test) by JPA and Oracle,  the Clob approach allowed me to resolve this this specific issue.

The issue I face now is that my *findByUuid(UUID uuid)* return an instance of MyClass where my payload has been instantiated with the implementation of oracle.sql.CLOB instead of the org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.ClobProxy implementation.

At some point the oracle implementation of Clob causes me troubles and I would like to avoid it. I also want to use hibernate implementation to have something similar to what is described in https://thoughts-on-java.org/mapping-blobs-and-clobs-with-hibernate-and-jpa/.

Does anyone know how I can force the result of my findByUuid(UUID uuid) to use hibernate implemenation of Clob instead of the oracle implementation?

Comment: I don't think you can 'avoid' using a JDBC driver's `Clob` implementation that Hibernate must rely on to handle large data. It seems you have an XY problem, though. If you could explain the *goal* of using `ClobProxy` and the *actual* problem with `CLOB`, perhaps we can suggest another solution

Comment: My payload is really big. When I run my "create_myclass" procedure, I get "StoredProcedureParameter ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error" (does not occur with smaller payload). Using Clob instead of String solved that issue. 

As for the CLOB oracle implementation (which causes me issue with my findByUuid(UUID uuid) method), I have the 2 following issue:
* (minor) most of the stuff from that class is deprecated so I would like to avoid it.
* (major) The getAsciiStream() method from Oracle Clob does not return the payload in the format I expect. The one from Hibernate does.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I realized that it is ok for me to work with the *oracle.sql.CLOB*. One of the reason I wanted to be able to recover an hibernate implementation of *Clob* is that following my *findByUuid(UUID uuid)* I was performing few operations on the returned *MyClass* and tried to saved it in my repository using the JPARepository save method (which resulted in a failure unless I converted the result to the Hibernate implementation of *Clob*).

I finally gave up trying to recover the hibernate implentation of *Clob*. And simply implemented a custom save method as shown in [How to add custom method to Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880924/how-to-add-custom-method-to-spring-data-jpa) (comment from kenny_k) where I convert the returned *oracle.sql.CLOB* to an instance of *org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.ClobProxy* before calling the JPA save method.

Comment: Please note that this question was raised following issues which are similar to what you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634638/hibernate-throws-sqlexception-could-not-reset-reader